# Spring Controller Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Recently I've got a problem with simple Spring MVC Application, particularly with controller.

Here is my controller code snippet:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String m1(Model model){
        return "form";
    }
}
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And here is bean configuration file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ua.macko.controller"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

In the jsps folder I've got two jsp files: hello.jsp and form.jsp.

When I'm trying to achieve root page of application, such as `http://localhost:8080/WebTest/` I'm ALWAYS getting hello.jsp REGARDLESS of what value I return in m1 method...whether it is "hello", "nothello", "iamnotapage" etc.

I am using Eclipse and Spring 3.2.8.

Comment: Is there a welcome/index file specified lower down in your `web.xml`?

Comment: Can you post the exception tree also?

Comment: Could you ensure that your application is well redeployed ?

Comment: What is the log output for the `org.springframework` logger with log level `ALL`?

Comment: @BeauGrantham no, is almost full web.xml file. There isn't only web-app tag? :(

Comment: @abhi There is no exception. Application works. But it doesn't work as it supposed to.

Comment: @yunandtidus Yes, it seems that is well redeployed.

Comment: Do one thing, delete hello.jsp (I mean move it to some where else if it is important) & try if you are still getting hello.jsp contents. If so, do Project -> Clean & re-deploy. If needed try cleaning up your browser cache also.

Comment: @abhi Thanks! I've tried this and it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start Spring application in log you should see something like this :

INFO: Mapped URL path [/] onto handler 'welcomeController'

1. If you do not see your controller on this list it means you should check:
   context:component-scan base-package="ua.macko.controller"
   because your controller is not visible to Spring
2. If you see two mappings than yours is overridden.
3. If you do not see any mapping like this than most probably Beau Grantham is right, or some other config problem is there.

Comment: INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String ua.macko.controller.MController.m1()

Comment: I've noticed that it maps the request on the MController.m1 method. But I have deleted it and wrote new class - MyController. How is it possible? O_O

Comment: Which IDE you are using? How you are building your project? If you are using Eclipse is Build Automatically enabled? If you are using Maven, try clean install.

Answer (score -2):

Is the path correct? I see you have jsps, try /WEB-INF/jsp/?

```
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
    </bean>
```

Comment: What do you think this would change?

Comment: The path to jsp files is correct. If it was the case there would be an error or something, but i've got no errors.